# Adding new div on button click

Tags: javascript, html

**I have seen similar questions but they haven't provided me a close solution.
Add the new div `<div class="container" id="section"style="border: 1px solid grey;">` and all the tables and fields hold with this `div` on a button click.
I'm trying to append it by following code.

```
function run() {

    var div = document.createElement("div"); //create new div
    div.addEventListener("click", run); //bind click to new div
    this.appendChild(div); //append the new div to clicked div
    this.removeEventListener("click", run); //remove the original click event

}
document.getElementById("section").addEventListener("click", run);
```

Can anyone please help me to sort this out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I recommend assigning the html to a string variable and then just appending it to a div when the button is clicked - sorry I can't be more help, I deal with jQuery which I know is just an extension of JS but the more I use it, the more I forget traditional js xD

Comment: Add this code `document.getElementById("section")..removeEventListener("click", run);` instead of  `this.removeEventListener("click", run); //remove the original click event`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to clone an entire section (including its children) on a button click and append that below the original.

You can do that with `cloneNode(true)` - but be aware that it will copy any field names (such as those on inputs).

`container.appendChild(sourceNode.cloneNode(true))`

```js
document.getElementById("newsectionbtn").onclick = function() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var section = document.getElementById("mainsection");
  container.appendChild(section.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```css
section { border:1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="newsectionbtn">+New Section</button>
  <section id="mainsection">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Field 1</th>
        <th>Field 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="f1" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="f2" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

click inside red square)

```js
function run() {

    var div = document.createElement("div"); //create new div
    div.addEventListener("click", run); //bind click to new div
    this.append(div); //append the new div to clicked div
    this.removeEventListener("click", run); //remove the original click event

}
document.getElementById("section").addEventListener("click", run);
```

```css
div{
border: 4px solid red;
padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button id="section">run</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.This is not what I am lookin for.
Consider a table. I am adding my fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/9qene19o/ 
There is a button called " Add Section " when clicked entire div has to repeat.